# After refres keep the last positioning of droppable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, droppable

I have a problem with .droppable event, I have two sections on which I can move my elements but after the page is refreshed my positioning is returning to initial position.
So what must be done in order to keep my last positioning of elements after the page is refreshed?

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jhogervorst/CPA5Y/

HTML:

```
<div class="group">
    <h1>Group 1</h1>

    <ul class="parent">
        <li class="droppable"><span class="draggable">Item 1</span></li>
        <li class="droppable"><span class="draggable">Item 2</span></li>
        <li class="droppable"></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="group">
    <h1>Group 2</h1>

    <ul class="parent">
        <li class="droppable"><span class="draggable">Item 3</span></li>
        <li class="droppable"></li>
        <li class="droppable"><span class="draggable">Item 4</span></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
body { font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; }
h1 { font-weight: bold; margin-bottom: 10px; }

.group {
    width: 150px;
    margin: 5px 0 5px 5px;
    float: left;
}

.parent {
    list-style-type: none;
}

.parent li {
    height: 41px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    background: #ddd;
}

.parent li.active {
    background: yellow;
}

.parent li.hover {
    background: orange;
}

.parent li.hover span {
    opacity: .5;
}

.parent li span {
    display: block;
    height: 25px;
    line-height: 25px;
    padding: 5px;
    background: #eee;
    border: 3px solid #eee;
    cursor: move;
}

.parent li span.ui-draggable-dragging {
    z-index: 10;
    border-color: red;
}



$(".draggable").draggable({
    revert: true,
    revertDuration: 0
});
```

jQuery:

```
$(".droppable").droppable({
    activeClass: "active",
    hoverClass: "hover",

    accept: function (draggable) {
        // The droppable (li element).
        var droppable = $(this);

        // The droppable which contains the draggable, i.e., the parent element of the draggable (li element).
        var draggablesDropable = draggable.parent();

        // Is the draggable being dragged/sorted to the same group?
        // => We could just sort it, because there's always enough space inside the group.
        if (droppable.parent().is(draggablesDropable.parent())) {
           return true;
        }

        // Nope, the draggable is being dragged/sorted to another group.
        // => Is there an empty droppable left in the group to which the draggable is being dragged/sorted?
        else if (droppable.parent().find(".draggable").size() < droppable.parent().find(".droppable").size()) {
            return true;
        }

        // Nothing true?
        return false;
    },

    drop: function(event, ui) {
        // The droppable (li element).
        var droppable = $(this);

        // The draggable (span element).
        var draggable = ui.draggable;

        // The droppable which contains the draggable, i.e., the parent element of the draggable (li element).
        var draggablesDropable = draggable.parent();

        // Is the draggable being dragged to it's own droppable?
        // => Abort, there's nothing to drag/sort!
        if (droppable.is(draggablesDropable)) {
            return;
        }

        // Is the draggable being dragged to an empty droppable?
        else if (!droppable.find(".draggable").size()) {
            // Just drop the draggable there.
            droppable.append(draggable);
        }

        // Is the draggable being dragged/sorted to the same group?
        // => We can just sort it, because there's always enough space inside the group.
        else if (droppable.parent().is(draggablesDropable.parent())) {
            // Is the draggable being dragged up?
            if (droppable.parent().find(".droppable").index(draggablesDropable) > droppable.parent().find(".droppable").index(droppable)) {
                // Add the dragged draggable's droppable before the droppable.
                draggablesDropable.insertBefore(droppable);
            }

            // No, the draggable is being dragged down.
            else {
                // Add the dragged draggable's droppable after the droppable.
                draggablesDropable.insertAfter(droppable);
            }
        }

        // Nope, the draggable is being dragged/sorted to another group.
        // => Is there an empty droppable left in the group to which the draggable is being dragged/sorted?
        else if (droppable.parent().find(".draggable").size() < droppable.parent().find(".droppable").size()) {
            // Find the first empty droppable in which the draggable is being dragged/sorted.
            var emptyDroppable = $($.grep(droppable.parent().find(".droppable"), function (item) {
                // Are there draggables inside this droppable?
                // => Return TRUE if not.
                return !$(item).find(".draggable").size();
            })).first();

            // Clone the dragged draggable's droppable before itself, because we need to remember it's position after moving it.
            var draggablesDropableClone = draggablesDropable.clone().insertBefore(draggablesDropable);

            // Is the draggable being dragged above the empty droppable?
            if (droppable.parent().find(".droppable").index(emptyDroppable) > droppable.parent().find(".droppable").index(droppable)) {
                // Add the dragged draggable's droppable before the droppable.
                draggablesDropable.insertBefore(droppable);
            }

            // No, the draggable is being dragged below the empty droppable.
            else {
                // Add the dragged draggable's droppable after the droppable.
                draggablesDropable.insertAfter(droppable);
            }

            // Remove the position of the dragged draggable, because there's still some css left of the dragging.
            draggable.css({"top": 0, "left": 0});

            // Add the first empty droppable before the cloned draggable's droppable. Remove the latter afterwards.
            draggablesDropableClone.before(emptyDroppable).remove();
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The position won't be saved on the page. You can either pass the position to server and store them there. Or create a cookie to store the position.

Comment: yes, but hot can I pass the position to the server? this was in my mind first but I don't know how :| I use wicket 1.4 and on this version I cannot use droppable event :(.

Comment: Ugh.. never used wicket really. Maybe create a button that would make a ajax request to server, sending the item# and position of those items. Then make a service page on server to accept the request and store the information?